# How to edit a text content of a multiple Div elements in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

i started learning programming(JavaScript) 5 months ago and i need your help.it is about an online bookshop(with add/delete and search function), the issue is i am trying to make a function which allow users to edit informations about the book like book name  ,price ,description etc..using a Bootstrap Modal.
i tried everything event.target for-loop etc.. but it doesn't work.i maked a solution(see the code below) but i have to set a different Id for every element which is bad idea.
Can you help please?
I thank everyone in advance

https://codepen.io/Sam_2018/pen/QZMPmX

> 

```js
var form = document.getElementById("addBook");
form.addEventListener("submit", addCard);
var cardList = document.getElementById("books");

function addCard(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // delete Button------------------------
    var icon = document.createElement("i");
    icon.className = "far fa-trash-alt";
    var delBtn = document.createElement("button");
    delBtn.className = "btn-sm btn-outline-danger m-1 delete";
    delBtn.appendChild(icon);

    //h5 and P-------------------
    var headline = document.createElement("h5");
    headline.className = "card-title";
    var bookName = document.getElementById("bookName").value;
    localStorage.setItem("title", bookName);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("title"));

    var title = document.createTextNode(bookName);
    headline.appendChild(title);
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    para.className = "card-text";
    var bookDescription = document.getElementById("message-text").value;
    var description = document.createTextNode(bookDescription);
    para.appendChild(description);
    var div1 = document.createElement("div");
    div1.className = "card-body";
    div1.appendChild(headline);
    div1.appendChild(para);

    //ul and li--------------
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.className = "list-group-item";
    var autor = document.getElementById("autor-name").value;
    var autorName = document.createTextNode(autor);
    li.appendChild(autorName);
    var ul = document.createElement("ul");
    ul.className = "list-group list-group-flush";
    ul.appendChild(li);

    // buy button-----------------------
    var buyBtn = document.createElement("button");
    buyBtn.className = "btn btn-warning mb-2";
    var price1 = document.getElementById("price").value;
    var bookPrice = document.createTextNode("Buy Now for" + " " + price1 + " €");
    buyBtn.appendChild(bookPrice);
    //----------------------

    var generalDiv = document.createElement("div");
    generalDiv.className = "card m-2 text-center col-3";
    generalDiv.id = "sam";
    generalDiv.style = "width: 18rem;";
    generalDiv.appendChild(delBtn);
    generalDiv.appendChild(div1);
    generalDiv.appendChild(ul);
    generalDiv.appendChild(buyBtn);
    cardList.appendChild(generalDiv);
    delBtn.addEventListener("click", deleteListElement);
    var addBtn = document.getElementById("btnContainer");
    addBtn.parentNode.insertBefore(generalDiv, addBtn);

}


var del = document.getElementsByClassName("delete");
for (var i = 0; i < del.length; i++) {
    del[i].addEventListener("click", deleteListElement);
}
function deleteListElement() {
    //remove the parent of button from its grand parent
    this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
}


function searchBook() {
    var input, filter, section, divs, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("search");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    section = document.getElementById("books");
    divs = section.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        a = divs[i].getElementsByTagName("h5")[-0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            divs[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            divs[i].style.display = "none";

        }
    }
}

editBook.addEventListener("submit", bas);
function bas(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var newtxt = document.getElementById("bookName").value;
    document.getElementById("sam2").textContent = newtxt;
    console.log(newtxt);
}
```

```css
#search{
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
#addBtn1{
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border:3px solid skyblue;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

    <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control  col-3 " onkeyup="searchBook()" placeholder="Search for Books...">

    <div class="row d-flex m-5 bg-dark justify-content-center " id="books">

        <div id="sam" class="card m-2 text-center col-3">
            <button class="btn-sm btn-outline-danger m-1 delete "><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
            <button id="editor" type="button" class="btn-sm btn-outline-success m-1 " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"
                data-whatever="@mdo">Edit </i></button>
            <img class="card-img-top" src="/saveus2.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            <h5 id="sam2" class="card-title">SAVE US</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Ruby steht unter Schock: Sie wurde vom
                Maxton-Hall-College suspendiert. Und
                das
                Schlimmste: Alles deutet darauf hin, dass niemand ...</p>
            <!--   <div onClick="this.contentEditable='true';">
                    lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolorlorem ipsum dolor
                </div> -->
            <h4>Mona Kasten</h4>
            <button class="btn btn-warning mb-2 ">Buy Now for 29.99 €</button>

        </div>
        <div id="sam" class="card m-2 text-center col-3">
            <button class="btn-sm btn-outline-danger m-1 delete "><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
            <img class="card-img-top" src="/download (1).jpeg" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Das Orakel</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Ruby steht unter Schock: Sie wurde vom Maxton-Hall-College suspendiert. Und
                    das
                    Schlimmste: Alles deutet darauf hin, dass niemand ...</p>
            </div>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item">Daphne Niko</li>

            </ul>

            <button class="btn btn-warning mb-2">Buy Now for 39.99 €</button>
        </div>
        <div id="sam" class="card m-2 text-center col-3">
            <button class="btn-sm btn-outline-danger m-1 delete "><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
            <img class="card-img-top" src="/download.jpeg" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Der Outsider</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia hic, velit ab
                    harum autem soluta ex ...</p>
            </div>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item">Stephen King</li>
            </ul>
            <button class="btn btn-warning mb-2">Buy Now for 29.99 €</button>
        </div>
        <div id="sam" class="card m-2 text-center col-3">
            <button class="btn-sm btn-outline-danger m-1 delete "><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
            <img class="card-img-top" src="/61iAgN-A3cL._SY346_.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Die Stadt der Träumenden Bücher</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Ruby steht unter Schock: Sie wurde vom Maxton-Hall-College suspendiert. Und
                    das
                    Schlimmste: Alles deutet darauf hin, dass niemand ...</p>
            </div>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item">Walter Moers</li>
            </ul>
            <button class="btn btn-warning mb-2">Buy Now for 29.99 €</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Book Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bookName">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Autor Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="autor-name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Price:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Book Description:</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <form id="addBook" class="form-inline ">
                            <input id="myBtn" type="submit" class="form-control m-2 btn btn-warning" value="Add">
                        </form>
                        <form id="editBook" class="form-inline ">
                            <input id="myBtn" type="submit" class="form-control m-2 btn btn-success" value="edit">
                        </form>
                        <!-- <button id="editBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-success m-1  " data-toggle="modal"
                            data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">edit</i></button> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="btnContainer" class="  align-self-center ">
            <button id="addBtn1" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success m-5 " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"
                data-whatever="@mdo"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>

            </button></div>
    </div>


    <script src="/main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is you example data is not getting pre populated while editing ? Right?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var form = document.getElementById("addBook");
form.addEventListener("submit", addCard);
var cardList = document.getElementById("books");

function addCard(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // delete Button------------------------
    var icon = document.createElement("i");
    icon.className = "far fa-trash-alt";
    var delBtn = document.createElement("button");
    delBtn.className = "btn-sm btn-outline-danger m-1 delete";
    delBtn.appendChild(icon);

    //h5 and P-------------------
    var headline = document.createElement("h5");
    headline.className = "card-title";
    var bookName = document.getElementById("bookName").value;
    localStorage.setItem("title", bookName);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("title"));

    var title = document.createTextNode(bookName);
    headline.appendChild(title);
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    para.className = "card-text";
    var bookDescription = document.getElementById("message-text").value;
    var description = document.createTextNode(bookDescription);
    para.appendChild(description);
    var div1 = document.createElement("div");
    div1.className = "card-body";
    div1.appendChild(headline);
    div1.appendChild(para);

    //ul and li--------------
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.className = "list-group-item";
    var autor = document.getElementById("autor-name").value;
    var autorName = document.createTextNode(autor);
    li.appendChild(autorName);
    var ul = document.createElement("ul");
    ul.className = "list-group list-group-flush";
    ul.appendChild(li);

    // buy button-----------------------
    var buyBtn = document.createElement("button");
    buyBtn.className = "btn btn-warning mb-2";
    var price1 = document.getElementById("price").value;
    var bookPrice = document.createTextNode("Buy Now for" + " " + price1 + " €");
    buyBtn.appendChild(bookPrice);
    //----------------------

    var generalDiv = document.createElement("div");
    generalDiv.className = "card m-2 text-center col-3";
    generalDiv.id = "sam";
    generalDiv.style = "width: 18rem;";
    generalDiv.appendChild(delBtn);
    generalDiv.appendChild(div1);
    generalDiv.appendChild(ul);
    generalDiv.appendChild(buyBtn);
    cardList.appendChild(generalDiv);
    delBtn.addEventListener("click", deleteListElement);
    var addBtn = document.getElementById("btnContainer");
    addBtn.parentNode.insertBefore(generalDiv, addBtn);

}


var del = document.getElementsByClassName("delete");
for (var i = 0; i < del.length; i++) {
    del[i].addEventListener("click", deleteListElement);
}
function deleteListElement() {
    //remove the parent of button from its grand parent
    this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
}


function searchBook() {
    var input, filter, section, divs, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("search");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    section = document.getElementById("books");
    divs = section.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        a = divs[i].getElementsByTagName("h5")[-0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            divs[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            divs[i].style.display = "none";

        }
    }
}

editBook.addEventListener("submit", bas);
function bas(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var newtxt = document.getElementById("bookName").value;
    document.getElementById("sam2").textContent = newtxt;
    console.log(newtxt);
}

$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
  var title = button.data('title');
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-body input#bookName').val(title)
})
```

```css
#search{
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
#addBtn1{
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border:3px solid skyblue;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

    <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control  col-3 " onkeyup="searchBook()" placeholder="Search for Books...">

    <div class="row d-flex m-5 bg-dark justify-content-center " id="books">

        <div id="sam" class="card m-2 text-center col-3">
            <button class="btn-sm btn-outline-danger m-1 delete "><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
            <button id="editor" type="button" class="btn-sm btn-outline-success m-1 " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"
                data-title="SAVE US">Edit </i></button>
            <img class="card-img-top" src="/saveus2.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            <h5 id="sam2" class="card-title">SAVE US</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Ruby steht unter Schock: Sie wurde vom
                Maxton-Hall-College suspendiert. Und
                das
                Schlimmste: Alles deutet darauf hin, dass niemand ...</p>
            <!--   <div onClick="this.contentEditable='true';">
                    lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolorlorem ipsum dolor
                </div> -->
            <h4>Mona Kasten</h4>
            <button class="btn btn-warning mb-2 ">Buy Now for 29.99 €</button>

        </div>
        <div id="sam" class="card m-2 text-center col-3">
            <button class="btn-sm btn-outline-danger m-1 delete "><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
            <img class="card-img-top" src="/download (1).jpeg" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Das Orakel</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Ruby steht unter Schock: Sie wurde vom Maxton-Hall-College suspendiert. Und
                    das
                    Schlimmste: Alles deutet darauf hin, dass niemand ...</p>
            </div>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item">Daphne Niko</li>

            </ul>

            <button class="btn btn-warning mb-2">Buy Now for 39.99 €</button>
        </div>
        <div id="sam" class="card m-2 text-center col-3">
            <button class="btn-sm btn-outline-danger m-1 delete "><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
            <img class="card-img-top" src="/download.jpeg" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Der Outsider</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia hic, velit ab
                    harum autem soluta ex ...</p>
            </div>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item">Stephen King</li>
            </ul>
            <button class="btn btn-warning mb-2">Buy Now for 29.99 €</button>
        </div>
        <div id="sam" class="card m-2 text-center col-3">
            <button class="btn-sm btn-outline-danger m-1 delete "><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
            <img class="card-img-top" src="/61iAgN-A3cL._SY346_.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Die Stadt der Träumenden Bücher</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Ruby steht unter Schock: Sie wurde vom Maxton-Hall-College suspendiert. Und
                    das
                    Schlimmste: Alles deutet darauf hin, dass niemand ...</p>
            </div>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item">Walter Moers</li>
            </ul>
            <button class="btn btn-warning mb-2">Buy Now for 29.99 €</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Book Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bookName">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Autor Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="autor-name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Price:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Book Description:</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <form id="addBook" class="form-inline ">
                            <input id="myBtn" type="submit" class="form-control m-2 btn btn-warning" value="Add">
                        </form>
                        <form id="editBook" class="form-inline ">
                            <input id="myBtn" type="submit" class="form-control m-2 btn btn-success" value="edit">
                        </form>
                        <!-- <button id="editBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-success m-1  " data-toggle="modal"
                            data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">edit</i></button> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="btnContainer" class="  align-self-center ">
            <button id="addBtn1" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success m-5 " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"
                data-whatever="@mdo"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>

            </button></div>
    </div>


    <script src="/main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much it works perfectly here,but not with my editor ,i think I've got something left over.